# Using native vtable-based DLL interface from C#

Tags: c#, com-interop

Some time ago I wrote a Windows DLL in C++ to encapsulate some functionality that I wanted to share between different C++ and Delphi compilers. I always liked the way that COM allows me to work with objects in contrast to having a flat C API in a DLL. Since for this DLL I did not need the full power of COM and no reference counting, I decided to implement a DLL interface that somewhat mimics COM. I have a single exported C function that allows me to create an object and returns an vtable interface pointer. Via this pointer I can call methods on the object in a compiler neutral way in  C++ and Delphi. When I'm done using the interface pointer, I call release on it.

Now I would like to use this DLL from C# but I don't know how to import the interface. Moreover I have a callback interface that the C# client must implement. Following is the C++ interface header file (somewhat shortended).

```
struct CksReadParams
{
    ...
};


struct ICksAdapter
{
    virtual ~ICksAdapter();

    virtual int32_t __cdecl Release() = 0;
    virtual int32_t __cdecl ReadValues(CksReadParams* params) = 0;
};


struct ICksAdapterCallback
{
    virtual ~ICksAdapterCallback();

    virtual void __cdecl OnConnected(int32_t clientID) = 0;
    virtual void __cdecl OnData(int32_t clientID, const char* csvLine) = 0;
    virtual void __cdecl OnLog(int32_t clientID, const char* message) = 0;
    virtual void __cdecl OnError(int32_t clientID, int32_t code, const char* message) = 0;
};


extern "C"
{
    typedef int(__cdecl *CA_PCreateAdapter)(ICksAdapterCallback* callback, ICksAdapter** adapter);

    __declspec(dllexport) int32_t __cdecl CA_CreateAdapter(ICksAdapterCallback* callback, ICksAdapter** adapter);
}
```

Can you give me a sketch on how to use this from C#, especially how to implement the callback interface, how to handle the __cdecl calling convention and how to handle char* parameters in the callback which are actually UTF8 encoded C++ strings?

Comment: Couldn't you just use COM? It seems wasteful for you to reinvent all that plumbing just for one custom DLL.

Comment: For one thing this DLL is already in use by other software so I have no choice anymore. But as I mentioned I did not want to reinvent all that plumbing! All I wanted was a vtable based object that I finally can release. From C++ and Delphi this is super simple to use.

Comment: If you insist on attempting this, my suggestion would be that you go get [Adam Nathan's](http://www.amazon.com/NET-COM-Complete-Interoperability-Guide/dp/067232170X) book, which has the most comprehensive coverage that I've seen of these topics. It's getting a bit long in the tooth but should still be relevant for what you want to do. For what it's worth I believe what you want to do here is possible but far from trivial.

Comment: `OnConnected`, `OnData`, `OnLog`... it appears you are connecting to something and mucking about with the data you get back.. certainly something you can do natively in C#.. would not writing the functionality in C# be easier?

Comment: @Sam: might be, but the device communication protocol implemented in the native DLL is quite complicated and needs a lot of pointer arithmetic. That's why I thought it would be nice to be able to reuse it.

Comment: @500ISE: actually I own Nathans book but was somewhat overwhelmed by the more than 1000 pages so I thought someone already knows how to do it. Anyway, the key seems to be the new Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate and its counterpart which are not described in the book, at least not in my edition. If you are interested how I solved it, see the code I just posted.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the following code that seems to do what I need. It was mainly inspired by this blog post [Implementing an unmanaged C++ interface callback](http://xoofx.com/blog/2010/10/25/implementing-unmanaged-c-interface/). The code builds mainly on Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer and Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate which are available starting with .NET 4.5 which is acceptable in my case. To sum up, you need to know the vtable of the C++ object and you need to fake a vtable in unmanaged memory for the callback interface.

If it's worth the effort I will leave to the reader. In my case it at least allows me to reuse my DLL. Next time I will probably stick with a flat C API or use COM in the first place.

```
class CksAdapterCallback
{       
    private IntPtr instance;

    public CksAdapterCallback()
    {
        instance = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(IntPtr.Size * 6);

        IntPtr vtblPtr = IntPtr.Add(instance, IntPtr.Size);
        Marshal.WriteIntPtr(instance, vtblPtr);

        Marshal.WriteIntPtr(vtblPtr, IntPtr.Zero); //dummy entry for the destructor

        OnConnectedInternal = new OnConnectedDelegate(OnConnected);
        Marshal.WriteIntPtr(IntPtr.Add(vtblPtr, IntPtr.Size), Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(OnConnectedInternal));

        OnDataInternal = new OnDataDelegate(OnData);
        Marshal.WriteIntPtr(IntPtr.Add(vtblPtr, 2*IntPtr.Size), Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(OnDataInternal));

        ...
    }


    ~CksAdapterCallback()
    {
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(instance);
    }


    public IntPtr Instance
    {
        get { return instance; }
    }


    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    delegate void OnConnectedDelegate(IntPtr instance, Int32 clientID);
    OnConnectedDelegate OnConnectedInternal;

    void OnConnected(IntPtr instance, Int32 clientID)
    {
        ...
    }


    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    delegate void OnDataDelegate(IntPtr instance, Int32 clientID, IntPtr data);
    OnDataDelegate OnDataInternal;

    void OnData(IntPtr instance, Int32 clientID, IntPtr data)
    {
        ...
    }

    ...
}


class CksAdapterProxy
{        
    private IntPtr instance;

    public CksAdapterProxy(IntPtr instance)
    {
        this.instance = instance;

        IntPtr vtblPtr = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(instance, 0);

        IntPtr funcPtr = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(vtblPtr, 1 * IntPtr.Size);            
        ReleaseInternal = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer<ReleaseDelegate>(funcPtr);

        ...
    }


    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    delegate Int32 ReleaseDelegate(IntPtr instance);
    ReleaseDelegate ReleaseInternal;

    ...


    public Int32 Release()
    {
        return ReleaseInternal(instance);
    }

    ...
}


public class CksAdapterTest
{   
    [DllImport("CKS\\CksAdapter.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    static extern int CA_CreateAdapter(IntPtr adapterCallback, out IntPtr adapter);

    CksAdapterProxy adapter = null;
    CksAdapterCallback adapterCallback = new CksAdapterCallback();


    public CksAdapterTest()
    {            
        IntPtr nativeAdapter = IntPtr.Zero;
        int result = CA_CreateAdapter(adapterCallback.Instance, out nativeAdapter);

        if(result == 0)
        {
            adapter = new CksAdapterProxy(nativeAdapter);

            ...

            adapter.Release();
        }
    }
}
```